# Change field value on return of database query in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Hello I am relatively new to Laravel / PHP and I have a question. When I do a database search, one of the fields in the database called local return returns a number from 1 to 4. But in the view, I should show the user text '1' = 'above' '2' = 'below' '3' = 'left' '4' = 'right'

I was wondering if there is a way to put these predefined values in the model without me having to make this change "manually" using if in view

Comment: please put some code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use laravel mutator for that. For doing that plqce the below code in your model

```
public function getUserTextAttribute($value)
{
    If($this->yourColumnName == 1)
         return  "Above";
    elseif($this->yourColumnName == 2)
         return  "below";
    elseif($this->yourColumnName == 3)
         return  "left";
    elseif($this->yourColumnName == 4)
         return  "Right";
}
```

And in your controller

```
 $user=User::find(1);
 return view('yourBladeFile', compact ('user')) ;
```

And in your blade file call the function which is we created in the model

```
 {{$user->Usertext}}
```

Comment: Good to hear that